# If I say "you will be paid up to today's date"

Tags: phrase-requests

Does that mean you will be paid for the period ending the day before today or the period ending on today?

e.g. if today is the 31st August, do I pay until the end of August or until the 30th?

Comment: In American English, you would need to say *"you will be paid up **through** today's date"* to convey that you are paid for today. I don't believe this works in British English.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase is not particularly clear, but "up to today" seems to imply "through yesterday" rather than "through today."

The problem is compounded because a lot of "business English" has been construed by the courts, and the law has its own vocabulary. If you want a good example, just ask a lawyer what "consideration" means legally. What is good standard English is not necessarily good law.

Personally, I try avoid using phrases that invite a legal interpretation. No one needs to say "up to the first day of the month" if what one means is "through the last day of the month." No one will be in doubt about what the latter means. "Business English" is frequently bad English.